# Setting up Company directory in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, directory

I am trying to set up our company directory in SharePoint Online and we have Azure AD. I have my welcome page Search people site set up but it doesn't pull anything in. When I try to run a search it comes back empty. I am trying to set up a company directory that is searchable but I am not having any luck.What am I missing?

Comment: you need to provide some more detail. "I built this thing and it doesn't work" isn't helpful. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [People Directory web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-people-directory.md) which is part of the [SharePoint starter kit](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit) managed by the PnP team. The SharePoint starter kit is fairly easy to deploy to your environment and comes with a number of other great web parts.